# During endpoints testing using mocha, why is my token undefined if it worked the first time?

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js, supertest

This is my first time doing tests in javascript and I went for making endpoint tests using mocha and supertest. Some endpoints require authentication and therefore I need to pass a token in a header. This is my code:

```
const chai = require('chai');
require('dotenv').config({ path: __dirname + '/.env.test' });
const { describe } = require('mocha');
const expect = chai.expect;
const { userIds, addDummyObjects } = require('./seed/seed');
const supertest = require('supertest');
const app = require('../app');
const dropAllCollections = require('./helpers/testHelper');
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

const server = supertest.agent(app);
let token= '';

before(async () => {
    addDummyObjects();
    await server.post('/user/login')
        .type('json')
        .send({
            "username": "testUser1",
            "email": "a@c.com",
            "password": "123456"
        })
        .then(res => token = res.body.token);
});

describe('POST /register - success', () => {
    it('should successfully register a user', async () => {
        const response = await server.post('/user/register')
            .send({
                "username": "anotherUser",
                "email": "a@c.com",
                "password": "123456"
            });

        expect(response.status).to.eql(200);
    });
});

describe('POST /register - fail', () => {
    it('should fail registering user due to username conflict', async () => {
        const response = await server.post('/user/register')
            .send({
                "username": "testUser1",
                "email": "a@c.com",
                "password": "123456"
            });

        expect(response.status).to.eql(400);
    });
});

describe('POST /login - success', () => {
    it('should login user and return token', async () => {
        const response = await server.post('/user/login')
            .send({
                "username": "testUser1",
                "password": "123456"
            });

        expect(response.status).to.eql(200);
        expect(response.body.auth).to.eql(true);
    });
});

describe('POST /login - fail', () => {
    it('should fail on login due to wrong password', async () => {
        const response = await server.post('/user/login')
            .send({
                "username": "testUser1",
                "password": "invalid password"
            });

        expect(response.status).to.eql(403);
    });
});

describe('GET /profile - success', () => {
    it('should authorize and return the user', async () => {
        const response = await server.get('/user/profile')
            .set('Authorization', `JWT ${token}`);

        expect(response.status).to.eql(200);
    });
});

describe('GET /profile/:id - success', () => {
    it('should authorize and return the information of the other user', async () => {
        const userId = userIds[0].toString();
        console.log(token);
        const response = await server.get(`/user/profile/${userId}`)
            .set('Authorization', `JWT ${token}`);

        expect(response.status).to.eql(200);
    });
});


after(async () => {
    await dropAllCollections();
    mongoose.connection.close();
});
```

Now, my problem is that the first time I executed those tests, all worked well, JWT was returned and all of my tests were a success. However, when I executed the tests for the second time, the token would be undefined and therefore I receive 'jwt malformed' error. This solution seemed to be optimal to me, since I used this method of getting jwt in other programming languages as well, but right here I'm getting errors and I don't know why.

If someone encountered this problem and could help me or direct me to some helpful material regarding my issue, I'll be really grateful!

**EDIT**: I got it working, in case there's anyone struggling with the same problem, I left 'addDummyObjects()' function in before hook and created beforeEach hook where I moved my post request for generating JWT and that solved my problem.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can use?

```
before(async () => {
    addDummyObjects();
});
beforeAll(async () => {
    await server.post('/user/login')
        .type('json')
        .send({
            "username": "testUser1",
            "email": "a@c.com",
            "password": "123456"
        })
        .then(res => token = res.body.token);
});
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.